# Unhandled Runtime Error -- TypeError: nextCreate is not a function --- "Not able to add rich-text-editor to webpage"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, shopify-app, polaris

Firstly I create react project then I installed jodit-react. When I run a program its showing error "self is not defined". then I add below code to my page.js.

const JoditEditor = dynamic(() => import("../../node_modules/jodit-react"), {
ssr: false,
});
And Now still getting this error

This is all dependencies:-
"dependencies": {
"jodit-react": "^1.3.39",
"next": "14.0.3",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18"
},

I added code but still not able to fetch rich-text-editor

This is my page.js code

1. "use client";
2. import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
3. import { useRef, useState useMemo } from "react";
4. export default function Home() {
5. const editor = useRef(null);
6. const [content, setContent] = useState('');
7. 
8. Define a placeholder or use an empty string if placeholder is not provided
9. const placeholder = ''; // Replace with your desired placeholder value
10. const config = useMemo({
11. readonly: false,
12. placeholder: placeholder || 'Start typing...',
13. [placeholder] );
14. const JoditEditor = dynamic(() => import("../../node_modules/jodit-react"), {
15. ssr: false,
16. });
17. return (
18. 
19. <JoditEditor
20. ref={editor}
21. value={content}
22. config={config}
23. tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
24. onBlur={newContent => setContent(newContent)}
25. onChange={newContent => {setContent(newContent)}} />
26. 
27. )}

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq8qf.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6NWT.png

This is are screenshots of Errors